# Need to display installed applications list

Tags: ios

Im developing on for iOS- supporting from iOS 5 and on

I need to create a button that will open for me a list of all applications installed on the device- through which i can send  messages

I have no idea where to even start

Answer (score 0):

You can't have the list of installed applications on iOS.
What you can do is use the URL Schemes.

[Here is Apple's URL Scheme Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/Introduction/Introduction.html)

[And here is a wiki with the URL Schemes for many iOS applications](http://wiki.akosma.com/IPhone_URL_Schemes)